# normal approximation in R wilcox.test()

Tags: r

I have a question about normal approximations in the wilcox.test() function.

I would intuitively expect the results of these calculation to be identical:

```
vec1 <- c(10,11,12)
wilcox.test(vec1,rep(0,10),exact=FALSE,correct = FALSE)
wilcox.test(vec1,c(runif(8),0,0),exact=FALSE,correct=FALSE)
```

but this is far from the case. (0.0006056 vs 0.01112)

From the wilcox.test documentation:

"an exact p-value is computed if the samples contain less than 50 finite values and there are no ties. Otherwise, a normal approximation is used."

It is unclear to me how the normal approximation is calculated based on the documentation. 
Searching the net (eg. wiki, Mann-Whitney U-test), it seems that it can be calculated by:

```
U = sum of ranks of vec1 (-1 in R)
mU = length(vec1)*length(vec2)/2
sdU = sqrt(length(vec1)*length(vec2)*(length(vec1)+length(vec2)+1)/12)
z = (U-mU)/sdU
pval = 2*pnorm(-abs(z))
```

But since U and the vector lengths in this case are identical, this obviously is not the way R calculates the normal approximation.

So my question is how the normal approximation is calculated by wilcox.test() in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inconsistency with formulas above is due to ties, which are taken into account in variance calculation. Below is `wilcox.test` code taken from 
[R source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/wilcox.test.R#L307)

```
NTIES <- table(r)
z <- STATISTIC - n.x * n.y / 2
SIGMA <- sqrt((n.x * n.y / 12) *
    ((n.x + n.y + 1) - sum(NTIES^3 - NTIES) 
    / ((n.x + n.y) * (n.x + n.y - 1))))
```

where `n.x`, `n.y` are lengths of first and second sample, `r` is rank vector of combined samples.

By the way, change `varU` to other name, as you took square root.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and pointing to sd being different from variance!! (changed)